# How to declare struct defined in different namespace?

Tags: c++, struct, namespaces

I'm having trouble using a struct that I declared in a different namespace. In File1.h I declare the struct and put it in namespace "Foo".

```
//File1.h
namespace Foo{
    struct DeviceAddress;
}

struct DeviceAddress {
    uint8_t systemID;
    uint8_t deviceID;
    uint8_t componentID;
};
```

In File2.c I try to create an instance of that struct:

```
//File2.c
#include "File1.h"
struct Foo::DeviceAddress bar;
```

But I get an error for the line in File2.c where I try to declare the struct. The error message is:
error C2079: 'bar' uses undefined struct 'Foo::DeviceAddress'

I'm using the MS C++ compiler with Visual Studio as a development environment.

Am I making some sort of syntax error trying to declare 'bar' or am I not understanding something about namespaces or structs?

Comment: You have to declare your `struct` residing in this namespace. A forward declaration isn't enough to get it into `Foo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two `DeviceAddress`es in `File1.h` are *not the same struct*: one is inside namespace `Foo`, the other is in the global namespace.

When you define a struct that's inside a namespace, you have to mention its namespace:

```
struct Foo::DeviceAddress {
    uint8_t systemID;
    uint8_t deviceID;
    uint8_t componentID;
};
```

Or simply declare and define it at the same time, which would be the recommended way:

```
namespace Foo{
    struct DeviceAddress {
        uint8_t systemID;
        uint8_t deviceID;
        uint8_t componentID;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the *definition* of your `struct`: it needs to be defined in the namespace too:

```
namespace Foo {
    struct DeviceAddress {
        uint8_t systemID;
        uint8_t deviceID;
        uint8_t componentID;
    };
}
```

You're currently defining a separate `Foo` in the global namespace.